# Pivoting DataFrame with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I need to transform this dataframe where the data is flat:

[image]

To something like the following, where in the index I have tmin and tmax for each date, and in the columns I have the name of the station (in the image only appears one name but there are more):

[image]

I have tried pivoting the table but I don't know how to make the multiIndex in the way I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can use [`df.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to split rows into `tmin` and `tmax` rows:

```python
melted = df.melt(id_vars=["date", "station"])
melted
```

```
          date    station   variable    value
0   1971-10-05  Station 1       tmin      7.3
1   1971-10-06  Station 1       tmin      4.4
2   1971-10-06  Station 2       tmin      4.8
3   1971-10-05  Station 1       tmax      8.2
4   1971-10-06  Station 1       tmax      7.3
5   1971-10-06  Station 2       tmax      7.1
```

Then, use `set_index` to "group" by date, variable and station, and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack) the last level (station):

```python
unstacked = melted.set_index(["date", "variable", "station"]).unstack()
# the next two lines just reformat/rename columns and index
# so that they look like the sample output you posted in your question
unstacked.columns = unstacked.columns.droplevel(0).rename(None)
unstacked.index = unstacked.index.rename(["date", "value"])
unstacked
```

```
                     Station 1  Station 2
      date  value       
1971-10-05   tmax          8.2        NaN
             tmin          7.3        NaN
1971-10-06   tmax          7.3        7.1
             tmin          4.4        4.8
```